# "User does not have administer or publishing privileges to item" error while publishing a multipart item in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am trying to publish a new item using multipart. Sometimes, our geojson files were too big, so we need to use multipart.

If I add only 1 part, it works fine.
If I add more than 1 part I get an error:

Here is a simplified version of my Python code after the authentication process:

```
add_item_params = {
    "f": "json",  # Specify the response format as JSON
    "title": feature_title,
    "filename": filename,
    "extension": "geojson",
    "type": 'GeoJSON',
    "token": self.token,
    "tags": "screenshot",
    "typeKeywords": "Coordinates Type, CRS, Feature, FeatureCollection, GeoJSON, Geometry, GeometryCollection, geojson",
    "multipart": "true"
}
# ADDING ITEM
response = requests.post("https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/<company user>/additem", 
    params=add_item_params, headers=headers, stream=True)

item_id = response.json()['id']

for index, single_geojson in enumerate(geojsons):
    add_part_params = {
        "f": "json",
        "partNum": (index + 1),
        "token": self.token,
    }
    # ADDING A NEW PART    
    requests.post(
"https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/<company>/items/<item_id>/addPart",
    params=add_part_params,
    files={'file': single_geojson},
    headers=headers)

# COMMITTING AFTER ALL ADD PARTS USING SAME PARAMS AS THE ADD ITEM REQUEST
requests.post(   "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/<company user>/items/<item_id>/commit",
    params=add_item_params,
    headers=headers, 
    stream=True)

time.sleep(10)
# PUBLISHING
publish_layer_params = {
    "f": "json",
    "token": self.token,
    "itemId": item_id,
    "filetype": "geojson",
    "publishParameters": json.dumps({"name": feature_title,
                                     "maxRecordCount": 2000,
                                     "hasStaticData": "True",
                                     "layerInfo": {"capabilities": "Query"}})
}
requests.post(
    'https://xxx.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/<company user>/publish',
    params=publish_layer_params, 
    headers=headers,
    stream=True)
```

The complete error that I get is:
"Unable to publish item.","details":["Item '' does not exist or is inaccessible.","Invalid item name","User '' does not have administer or publishing privileges to item ''."]}}

However, if I do the same, but have only 1 geojson to add, every thing works well